# Responsive design works on Mobile but does not adapt when resizing the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've created a responsive design for the first time and I was wondering what was not working... It is working perfectly on desktop, and also the mobile loads when it's on mobile, but I'd like the responsive design to also work when I'm resizing the page.

In my HTML file :

I have this chop of code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
      href="css/mobile.css" />
```

In my css file I have this

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
 /** My css **/
}
```

It's working perfectly, I'd only need the page to detect the mobile.css file when I resize the screen of my desktop. Usually responsive website does it, I'm pretty sure I could do this with jQuery but I think there must be an easier way to do this... Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 /* your css */
}
```

max-device-width -----> max-width:

Will work for both!!!